# Editing JSON file using Java ,where file is at remote location: SSH available

Tags: java, json

I have a JSON file in my linux box (remote). I am using `org.json.simple.*` library. I would like to just update one of the attributes and write it back.  In JSON file, I know there is one key with "XXXX" and its value is "YYYY". I want to update its value to "WWWWXYZ".

Below is code snippet on what is done so far

```
Channel channel = session.openChannel("sftp");
channel.connect();
ChannelSftp sftp = (ChannelSftp) channel;

InputStream stream = sftp.get(<JSON FILE LOCATION>);
try {
    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

    try {

        JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject)jsonParser.parse(
            new InputStreamReader(stream, "UTF-8")
        );

        System.out.println(jsonObject.toJSONString());

        jsonObject.put("XXXX", "WWWWXYZ");
        System.out.println(jsonObject.toJSONString());

    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

If you see, I was able to get the JSON file using SSH and then converted that to JSON Object, edited the JSON object. Now I would like to write back it to the actual file in linux box. Please help on how to write back my JSONObject to file, which is located at remote location (my linux box).

Comment: you can sftp the same file at <JSON FILE LOCATION>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I correctly understand, you should write your json object to a (optionally new) local file (see [here for an example on how to do it](https://dzone.com/articles/java-api-json-processing-%E2%80%93-0)) and then use your ChannelSftp put method to replace the remote file with your updated version.

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to putting file back to remote server then following code can help you. You can save modified JSON to one file in your local machine and then transfer that file to remote machine..

```
  channel = session.openChannel("sftp");
        channel.connect();            
        channelSftp = (ChannelSftp) channel;
        channelSftp.cd(SFTPWORKINGDIR);
        File f = new File(filename);
        channelSftp.put(new FileInputStream(f), f.getName());
```